# Using getchar() in a while loop or a do while loop

Tags: c, while-loop, do-while

I was recently reading C primer plus and I got a question:

```c
void foo1(int n, char ar[n])
{
    int i = 0;

    while ((ar[i] = getchar()) && !isblank(ar[i++]) && i < n)
        continue;
}
```

```c
void foo2(int n, char ar[n])
{
    int i = 0;
    do
        ar[i] = getchar();
    while (!isblank(ar[i++]) && i < n);
}
```

Seems they have the same output when being tested, but I still wonder:

Are the two functions euquiavalent?

When being compiled, do they generate the same compiled code?

If not, which one is more efficient?

Comment: Hint: what if the file contains a null character?

Comment: Note that both versions will misbehave if end-of-file or a read error should occur.

Comment: Do you need to null-terminate the output?  How does the calling code know how many characters were read?

Comment: Also they both cause undefined behaviour for negative chars (the argument to `isblank` must be non-negative)

Answer (score 0):

So, the `while` command checks the condition first, whereas the `do...while` executes the command within once, then checks the condition.

The `while` command is much more common than the `do...while` one, because most programmers do not want the loop executed once regardless of whether the condition are met.